# Shipping error, sales_flat_shipment_item missing along with all sales_flat... tables

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I was trying to ship an order through magento and got an error that starts with below (it's very long, didn't paste all of it.

When I went to look for that table I realized I don't have any tables that start with `sales_flat`. My tables stop at letter R, last table is `rating_option_vote`.

> a:5:{i:0;s:228:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'sales_flat_shipment_item' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
>   `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_shipment_item` AS `main_ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, this has got to be the stupidest one of my questions.
there's page 2 with the rest of the tables. the reason i'm getting an error is because that table has an apostrophe at the end. this happened to me before with another table, not sure what causes it.